# Every sequentially discrete space is totally path disconnected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

A topological space $X$ is [sequentially discrete](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000167) if every convergent sequence in $X$ is eventually constant.

A space $X$ is [totally path disconnected](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000046) if every path $f:[0,1]\to X$ is constant.

It seems the following should be true:

> **Proposition:** Every sequentially discrete space is totally path disconnected.

Can anyone provide a proof?

---

**Note**: One cannot deduce the stronger property that the space is totally disconnected.  For example, the cocountable topology on an uncountable set is sequentially discrete, but not totally disconnected.  It is in fact connected (even hyperconnected).

Comment: Hint: Show that $f$ is locally constant (arguing by contradiction).

Comment: If $X$ is sequentially discrete, then any map from a connected metric space into $X$ is constant, since it factors through the discrete sequential coreflection of $X$.

Comment: @Tyrone Nice.  The categorical characterization makes things very clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $f: [0,1] \rightarrow X$ is not constant.
$B := f([0,1])$ is connected. Since sequentially discrete spaces are obviously $T_1$, $B$ is infinte.
Hence there is a sequence $(r_n)_{n \in \mathbb N} \subset [0, 1]$, such that
$(f(r_n))_n$ is pairwise distinct. Since $[0, 1]$ is sequentially compact,
a subsequence $(r_n)_{n \in N}$ converges to an $r \in [0,1]$.
Hence $(f(r_n))_{n \in N}$ converges to $f(r)$ contradicting sequential discreteness.